Birational pullback of sheaf of differentials
Let $X\xrightarrow f Y$ is a birational morphism over positive characteristic, where $X$ is a smooth surface.
Assuming we know that $f^*K_Y \cong K_X$, can we conclude that $f^*\Omega_Y\cong\Omega_X$?

No. For instance, if $f$ is the blowup of an ordinary double point then the exceptional divisor $C$ of $f$ is a smooth rational $(-2)$-curve, hence the conormal bundle sequence takes the form
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_C(2) \to \Omega_X\vert_C \to \mathcal{O}_C(-2) \to 0.
$$
Any such extension splits, hence
$$
\Omega_X\vert_C \cong \mathcal{O}_C(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_C(-2).
$$
Since this bundle is not trivial, it is not a pullback from $Y$.

The cotangent bundle of X restricted to C has that direct sum decomposition. I presume you meant that, instead of simply writing $ \Omega_X $. In any case, that information is enough to get to your conclusion.

Sure, this was a typo, thanks for pointing.
